# Calling up a Table with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So Im trying to display a table when the user clicks on a image. I came pretty far, but Im stuck and cant seem to find my mistake.

When I open up my console I get the following error:

[image]

Now Hannibal is part of the group of users I want to display in the table.

I wont post the entire code, since its alot. Ill try to keep it to the relevant parts. In this case I know that I get into my .php file that executes the query.

Since I tested the Query, I know it works so Ill just show how I give it back in my separate .php File:

```
$Guest_Invite_Data = filterTable($List_Guests_Query);
$Guest_Invite_Data_fetched = mysqli_fetch_array($Guest_Invite_Data);

echo json_encode($Guest_Invite_Data_fetched);

function filterTable($query)  
{   
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
```

And heres part of my jQuery:

```
success:function(Guest_Invite_Data_fetched) {
    createTableByJqueryEach2(Guest_Invite_Data_fetched);
},
```

And heres my function:

```
function createTableByJqueryEach2(data2){

    var eTable2="<table><tr><th colspan='5'>Gäste einladen</th></tr><tr><th>Person</th></tr>"
    $.each(data2,function(index2, row2){

        eTable2 += "<tr>";
        $.each(row2,function(key2,value2){
            eTable2 += "<td>"+value2+"</td>";
        });
     eTable2 += "</tr>";
    });
    eTable2 +="</table>";
    $('#guest_table').html(eTable2);
 }
```

Does anybody spot my mistake?

Edit: Picture of Output as requested

[image]

Edit 2: Text of the Output as requested

```
Array ( [0] => Hannibal [firstname] => Hannibal [1] => Lecter [lastname] => Lecter [2] => Cannibals Inc. [name] => Cannibals Inc. ) {"0":"Hannibal","firstname":"Hannibal","1":"Lecter","lastname":"Lecter","2":"Cannibals Inc.","name":"Cannibals Inc."}
```

Comment: Have a look at what `Guest_Invite_Data_fetched` actually is.  It's looks like your function is expecting a nested array, while the error is saying you don't have (just) a nested array.

Comment: None of the code here matches the error you're displaying.

Comment: @freedomn-m Well the array would normally be multidimensional. The query grabs every user that is part of the group "guest". The function that creates the table thus probably expects a multidimensional array. Could it be that its confused because the array isnt multidimensional?

Comment: @JayBlanchard What is your best guess where an error like this could happen? Like I said the reason I dont post all of the code, remotely connected to this issue, is because I dont want too much code to confuse people.

Comment: Have a read of [mcve].  The key is to provide just *enough* code to reproduce the problem *within the question*.  In writing that code, quite often you will find the problem yourself, so it's a very useful exercise.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks! Yes Ive been posting here for 2-3 weeks only and still tend to make posts, that are a bit hard to understand. Ill give it a read and come back if there are any developments.

Comment: I'd love to see some of the output of `Guest_Invite_Data_fetched`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Added a screenshot of the Print_r of it to my post!

Comment: Please do not use screen shots for those things. Added them as text.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Alright. Added them as text :)

Comment: Code testing complete, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following as test code I find two things:

a. You're fetching both indexed and associative arrays from the database. Note in your JSON the numbered index and value, followed by the associative (column name) and value:

```
"0":"Hannibal","firstname":"Hannibal"
```

You should only fetch what you want. For example, I'd use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` here - giving me columns names and values.

b. You are looping through the data and then trying to loop through the resulting text:, which is what causes the error. For example, `row2` on the first iteration contains the value `Hannibal`, so you second loop is essentially trying to do this:

```
$.each('Hannibal',function(key2,value2){...
```

`Hannibal`, just being text, cannot be looped through like this. It has no keyss or values.

You only need one loop for this data. Here is the test code proving this out:

```
var guest_data =  {"0":"Hannibal","firstname":"Hannibal","1":"Lecter","lastname":"Lecter","2":"Cannibals Inc.","name":"Cannibals Inc."};

function createTableByJqueryEach2(data2){

    var eTable2="<table><tr><th colspan='5'>Gäste einladen</th></tr><tr><th>Person</th></tr>"
    $.each(data2,function(index2, row2){

        eTable2 += "<tr>";
        eTable2 += "<td>"+row2+"</td>";
        eTable2 += "</tr>";
    });
    eTable2 +="</table>";
    $('#guest_table').html(eTable2);
 }

 createTableByJqueryEach2(guest_data);
```

This results in the following:

```
<div id="guest_table">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">Gäste einladen</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Person</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hannibal</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lecter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cannibals Inc.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hannibal</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lecter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cannibals Inc.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It is likely you want to have a different layout, this is just what I did to prove out the error.

Comment: Wow! An extensive and well written answer! Not only providing me with the solution but actually teaching me what I did wrong and preventing me from doing the same mistake again! :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help @w00ds98